# When is the semidirect product of $(Z/pZ)^n$ and $(Z/qZ)^2$ generated by two elements?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I asked a very similar question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308340/22512) and got a wonderful answer.  But now I need to change the question slightly (this is the last question like this, I promise).

I would like to characterize when $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^2$ is a centerless group generated by two elements.  Here, $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes (you can assume both are odd if relevant).

There was a nice answer when the second factor was cyclic, and I’m wondering how this changes it.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think this holds if and only if $(Z/pZ)^n$ decomposes as a sum of distinct irreducibles $V_i$ over $(Z/qZ)^2$, where each $V_i$ is a faithful $(Z/qZ)$-module. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This problem came from a rather different-sounding problem in combinatorial group theory.  My collaborator and I have a bunch of pages describing the minimal groups that fail to do a condition we like.  Among other things, these minimal groups are centerless, generated by two elements, and they’re either (1) of the form in this question or (2) of the form in the linked question, which has the second factor cyclic.

Comment: Do you have a small example on hand for which a group described in this question exists?

Comment: I'm not sure what you call "minimal". Also I can't make any sense of the question "*o you have a small example on hand for which a group described in this question exists*" in your last comment.

Comment: (Minimal with respect to subquotients, but that doesn’t help much with my hypervague “condition we like” phrasing)  As for the example, I was wondering if you could give me a particular values of $p, q,$ and $n$ for which there exists a centerless group generated by two elements that’s of the form in the question.  (I’ll figure out the action)  [Honestly, I ask because I don’t know enough representation theory to parse your first comment, and I was hoping for something small I could hold in my hand to look at. (And I won’t see my usual representation theory friends for a week or so)]

Comment: Thanks for asking: actually I should amend my first comment: $V_i$ should not be assumed to be faithful, but $\bigoplus V_i$ should be faithful. Indeed, $V_i$ itself can't be faithful (this comes from the fact that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic). Then it's easy to get examples.

Comment: (Sorry to press, and thanks so much for your help.)  (i) The faithful part corresponds to the condition that it be centerless, right?  (ii) Can you let me know an example with say $p=5$ and $q=3$?  Or at least, what are some candidates for $n$ that I should be looking at?

Comment: Consider two distinct surjective homomorphisms $Z/qZ^2\to Z/qZ$ and consider two faithful irreducible $Z/pZ[Z/qZ]$-modules and view them as $Z/pZ[(Z/qZ)^2]$-modules through these surjective homomorphisms.

Comment: In the case $p=5$, $q=3$, irreducible modules have dimension $2$, and since there must be at least two of them, the smallest examples have order $5^4\times 3^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proof of YCor's claim that the group is $2$-generated if and only if $V:=(Z/pZ)^n$ is isomorphic as a $(Z/qZ)^2$-module to a direct sum of distinct nontrivial irreducible modules.

For the "only if" part it is sufficient to consder the case when $V = W \oplus W$ is a direct sum of two isomorphic modules, and to prove that $G$ is not $2$-generated in that case.

Suppose for a contradiction that $G$ is $2$-generated. Then the two generators must have the form $xv$ and $yw$, where  $\langle x, y \rangle \cong (Z/qZ)^2$ is a complement in the semidirect product, and $v,w \in V$. Since  $V$ is assumed to be nontrivial, $x$ and $y$ cannot both act trivially on $V$, so suppose that $x$ does not. Then $xv$ has order $q$ and is conjugate to $x$, so we may assume that $v=1$. But any element in $V$ is contained in a $(Z/qZ)^2$-submodule of $V$ isomorphic to $W$, so $\langle x,yb \rangle \le \langle x,y,b \rangle \ne G$, contradiction.

Conversely, suppose that $V \cong \oplus_{i=1}^k V_i$, with $V_i$ pairwise non-isomorphic $(Z/qZ)^2$-submodules, and let $0 \ne v_i \in V_i$.

Again by nontriviality, $x$ and $y$ cannot both act non-trivially on any $V_i$, and we can order the $V_i$ such that, for some $j$ with $0 \le j \le k$, $y$ acts nontrivially on $V_1,\ldots,V_j$  and $x$ acts nontrivially on $V_{j+1},\ldots,V_k$.

Let $H= \langle xv_1\cdots v_j, yv_{j+1}\cdots v_k \rangle \le G$. We claim that $H=G$.

To see this, observe that the commutator
$$ [ xv_1\cdots v_j, yv_{j+1}\cdots v_k] = [v_1,y]\cdots[v_j,y][x,v_{j+1}] \cdots [x,v_k], $$
which is a product of nontrivial elements, one from each $V_i$. The submodule of $V$ generated by this element projects nontrivially onto each $V_i$, and so it must be equal to $V$. Hence $V \le H$, so $H=G$ as claimed.

I think that if you allow trivial irreducible submodules of $V$ then, as in the previous problem, you can also have up to two of these in a $2$-generated group.

*PS*: I see that I missed the fact mentioned by YCor that $Z(G)=1$ implies that $V$ must be a faithful module.